# repaint() method doesn't work more than once

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I am currently working on a gui project which is managing a sql database. I am currently adding,deleting logs and showing tables existing in mysql. The problem is my add and delete buttons on my panel are supposed to repaint/refresh the table on that panel as a record is added or deleted however while testing I discovered that repaint method doesn't refresh the table after the first use of the button. What can cause this problem? Thanks in advance..

```
public JTabbedPane addComponentToPane() {
        //Container pane = new Container();
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card4 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card5 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card6 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card7 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card8 = new JPanel();

        card1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card5.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card6.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card7.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        card8.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JScrollPane actor = new JScrollPane(createTables("actor"));

        card1.add(actor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        card3.add(createTables("address"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        card4.add(createTables("category"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        card5.add(createTables("city"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        card6.add(createTables("country"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        card7.add(createTables("customer"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        card8.add(createTables("film"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Yeni Kayıt");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addRecord("actor");                
                card1.remove(actor);
                card1.add(createTables("actor"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                card1.validate();
                card1.repaint();                
            }
        });
        JButton delButton = new JButton("Kayıt sil");
        delButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delRecord("actor");
                card1.remove(actor);
                card1.add(createTables("actor"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                card1.validate();
                card1.repaint();
            }
        });``

        card1.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        card1.add(delButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        tabbedPane.addTab("Şirketler", null, card1, "şirket tanımları");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Sorumlular", card2);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Varlık Grupları", card3);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Bilgi Varlıkları", card4);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Varlık Değerleri", card5);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Açıklıklar", card6);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tehditler", card7);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Ek-A", card8);

        //pane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return tabbedPane;
    }
```

Create tables method creating a Jtable from sql table.

```
private JScrollPane createTables(String tablename) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String query;
        JScrollPane jsp = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "root", "root");
            statement = con.createStatement();
            query = "select * from " + tablename;
            result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmt = result.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmt.getColumnCount();
            Vector column = new Vector(columnCount);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                column.add(rsmt.getColumnName(i));
            }
            Vector data = new Vector();
            Vector row = new Vector();
            while (result.next()) {
                row = new Vector(columnCount);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                    row.add(result.getString(i));
                }
                data.add(row);
            }
            defTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, column);
            table = new JTable(defTableModel) {
                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                }
            ;
            };
            //table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            TableRowFilterSupport.forTable(table).searchable(true).apply();
            table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

            jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
        }
        finally {
            try {
                statement.close();
                result.close();
                con.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");
            }
        }

        return jsp;
    }
```

Comment: You could try calling `revalidate();repaint();` instead of `validate();repaint();`

Comment: I have already tried that but thanks for advice.

Comment: Can you post your `createTables()` function? Better yet, can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've added createTables() function.

Comment: There should be no need to explicitly call `repaint()` when updating a table.  Change the table model and the table will update.  Post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Tip: Add @KevinWorkman (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the tip. I know that a table must update itself when it is changed and tried to use the DefaultTableModel but it didn't work so I wanted to do it manually but now I have this repaint problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see couple of inconsistencies in the code:

1. The `actor` variable is not being set to the added component in the action listener.
2. First time you are adding `new JScrollPane(createTables("actor"))` and then onwards you only add `createTables("actor")`.

The (1) might be causing the problem.

Comment: That is not the problem. I have to do that because I have to recreate the table as the database is changed. If I add the actor variable again the function is not called for a second time and the old table will be added as it is not dynamic.

Comment: @Sertage made it more clear. If you can't use the actor because it need to be `final` you can either make it a member variable of class or use `removeAll` rather than `remove` in the action listener.

Comment: I think making actor variable a member variable is not a proper solution as it is just a case and removeAll function also removes the buttons from the panel which is unnecessary. Can you think of a way that I can delete just the table? Thank you.

Comment: A hackish way is to use `getComponents` and search for table within the panel.

Comment: I used this code and it works.Just for further use:Component[] components = card1.getComponents();
                for(Component component : components)
                    if(component instanceof JScrollPane)
                        card1.remove(component);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the reference to the actor:

```
card1.remove(actor);
card1.add(createTables("actor"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here, the variable actor is not more referenced in card1. To not lose this reference you should do something like this, in both actionPerformed methods:

```
card1.remove(actor);
actor = new JScrollPane(createTables("actor"));
card1.add(actor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Well I think you've found out the problem but I still don't have a solution because I get an error when I try to reference the actor variable saying "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final"

Comment: This is a dumb question but is making the variable final a viable option?